# How to set only the first cell of a UITableView to a different color?

Tags: ios, xcode

I use cellForRowAtIndexPath like here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
        cell = [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier];


    UILabel *lbl = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];

    for (UITableViewCell *c in [tbl visibleCells])
    {
     //   UITableViewCell *cell2 = [tbl cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
        UILabel *lbl = (UILabel*)[c.contentView viewWithTag:1];
        lbl.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    if([tbl indexPathForCell:cell].section==0)
        lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    UILabel *lblTemp1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *lblTemp2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

    //First get the dictionary object

    lblTemp1.text =  @"test!";
    lblTemp2.text = @"testing more";

    NSLog(@"%@",[tbl indexPathForCell:cell]);

    return cell;


}
```

But is still makes some of my cells white instead of gray.

How can I change only the first item in the row to white?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: ditch the

```
for (UITableViewCell *c in [tbl visibleCells])
{
    //UITableViewCell *cell2 = [tbl cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    UILabel *lbl = (UILabel*)[c.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    lbl.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

and change it to

```
UILabel *lbl = (UILabel*)[c.contentView viewWithTag:1];
lbl.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

no need to go trough all the visible cells here.

Then change

```
if([tbl indexPathForCell:cell].section==0)
        lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

to

```
if((indexPath.section==0)&&(indexPath.row==0))
        lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

If this class/object is delegate of several tableViews you should
add additional checking for

```
if ((tableView == correctTableView)&&...
```

It's worth to notice that

```
[tbl indexPathForCell:cell]
```

is irelevant. Your reference is parameter `(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

If problems persist you should post the code of your `getCellContentView:` method.

**EDIT:** according to rmaddy's advice and since `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is important performance-vise it would be better to use:

```
if((indexPath.section==0)&&(indexPath.row==0))
{
    lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
else
{
    lbl.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

This way you avoid unnecessary double change when dealing with first cell.

Comment: An `if` statement that conditionally changes the cell`s state must have an `else` statement that resets the change. Otherwise weird things will happen as cells are reused during scrolling.

Comment: The unconditional change to red would appear before the conditional change to white - so it would work normally. But you're right: the better way would be to use if/else

Comment: @rmaddy: i rearanged the parts of code so that they (should) make more sense

Comment: It would still be clearer is you wrote `if first row color = white else color = red`.